# How to create singleton function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

So I need to create a module in Haskell where we should use this data type

`data List x = LT [(x,[String])]`

and implement this function `singleton :: x -> List x`.

I've been searching to find if my solution `singleton elem = LT [(elem,[])]` is correct, but couldn't find any.

Is there anywhere I can find examples that are simple and well explained?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your implementation is a reasonable for a function named `singleton`. But since I don't know the assignment, that's all I can say.

Comment: @jpath, well is just like the signature says, receiving an element it returns an empty List of that element...

Comment: "returning an empty list of that element". That doesn't make sense. Do you mean returning a singleton list with just the pair of that element and the empty list?

Comment: @jpath, yes that.

Comment: I don't think the "singleton" tag is really appropriate here.  That tag is for the Gang of Four Singleton pattern, which implies that there is a single application-wide instance of something, and generally also that there is mutable state shared through that instance.  Here we're talking about a simple pure function that just returns a one element list, which is definitely not a GoF singleton.

Comment: @Mr.Putty, I agree that the tag doesn't fit here. In the context of Haskell, I'd expect the tag to relate to the `singletons` package, or more generally to  the technique of using a singleton GADT to bring type-level structures down to the term level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `x` is an unrestricted type variable, `singleton` cannot generate a valid value of type `x` by itself. It can only do one of two things:

1. Use the argument of type `x` that it receives.
2. Use `undefined`.

Your definition is certainly the most *reasonable* definition for the function; however, with no other information to go on, the following
are also *valid* definitions of `singleton :: x -> List x`:

1. `singleton elem = LT [(undefined,[])]`
2. `singleton elem = LT []`
3. `singleton elem = LT [(elem,[]), (elem,[])]`
4. `singleton elem = LT [(elem,["foo"])]`
5. `singleton elem = LT [(elem,["foo", "bar"])]`

The first uses `undefined` as the value of type `x`. The second and third take advantage of the fact that the *length* of list to return is unspecified. The fourth and fifth take advantage of the fact that neither the length nor the contents of the value with concrete type `[String]` is specified.